# C++:declaring a function that returns string in header file?

Tags: c++, string, header

In one of my modules, I have a function (changeNum) that returns a string and accepts a parameter that is a string. I tried to declare this function in my header file as following:

```
std::string changeNum(std::string s);
```

[and I included the string header file into the header file as well]

but I'm still getting the following error in my header file: "unknown type name 'string'" What do I do?

Here is the whole code:
My header file is the following:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
std::string changeNum(std::string s);
```

My module with the function changeNum is defined as the following

```
#include <string>
string changeNum(string s){
    return s;
}
```

Comment: paste the whole code

Comment: My header file is the following: #pragma once
#include <string>

string changeNum(string s);

Comment: and my current module function is just this for now: string changeNum(string s)
{
return s;
}

Comment: edit your question instead of adding code in comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Just modified the question, thank you!  Ah got it, thanks for letting me know it is "declare" and not "define."

Comment: Have you tried `std::string changeNum(std::string s){ return s; }`? It would be good to make a more complete example of the cpp file. Add the includes and any using statements.

Comment: I just tried that, and I still am getting the error: "unknown type name: string."

Comment: ^this error comes up in my header file!

Comment: I'm starting from very basic code, so I currently only have those lines in the header file and I have the changeNum in my module, and the only additional #include I have in this module is #include <string>

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

std::string changeNum(std::string s);
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

std::string changeNum(std::string s) {
    return s;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string sample_str = changeNum("Hello");
    std::cout << sample_str.c_str();
}
```

Tested on VS and removed `#include "pch.h"` from aforementioned code.